# problem with javascript Object , i always get [object Object] instead of the value i want

Tags: javascript, html

this is my HTML file

```
<body>
    <form id="myform" style="width:200px;margin:0 auto" >
        <select id="selectCountry" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle">
            <option>یک کشور را انتخاب کنید</option>
        </select>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    </form>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("selectCountry").selectedIndex;
        var result = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value;
        console.log(result); // this line gives [Object object]
    }
    </script>
    
</body>
```

`console.log(result);` gives back `[object Object]` no matter what i do.`

and this is my `.js` file

```
const api_url = 'https://api.covid19api.com/summary';
var dropDownSelector = document.getElementById('selectCountry');
var api_countries = [];
var api_getCountrySpecifics = [];

// Initializing The Api ///
    async function getData(url) {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        return data;
    }  

    getData(api_url).then(response => {
        
        for( var i=0 ; i < 190 ; i++ ) {
             api_countries.push(response.Countries[i].Country);
             api_getCountrySpecifics.push(response.Countries[i]);
        }

        for(var j = 0 ; j < 190 ; j++) {
            var opt = api_countries[j];
            var specifics = api_getCountrySpecifics[j]
            var el = document.createElement("option");
            el.textContent = opt;
            el.value = specifics;
            dropDownSelector.appendChild(el);
        }
});
```

Does anyone know what's the problem? it is very important to me to solve this.
thank you beforehand.

Comment: problem is `el.value = specifics;` assigns an object to an html attribute

Comment: Yeah! `specifics.Country` would be good

Comment: We *have* to have a duplicate for this in vanilla JS, but all I can find are posts focusing on jQuery.

Comment: You can clearly see on your code that `response.Countries[i]` is an object since you push its `Country` property on `api_countries`. It all boils down to... What do you want to do with this object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your API call is returning an array of objects but you are treating it like an array of strings.

On this line:

```
el.value = specifics;
```

`specifics` is an object and it is being automatically converted to a string, when that happens the JS engine turns it into `[Object object]`.

You need to examine that object and assign a string to the value instead of that whole object.

If you want the whole object to be the value, you need to stringify it first and then decode it later...

```
el.value = JSON.stringify(specifics);
```

And then...

```
var result = JSON.parse(document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the data is in `object` and you need to convert that `object` into value.

So, For that you can simply assign a `variable` and then check the value in the console.

```
let value = JSON.stringify(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```js
var result = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value;
```

try

```js
var result = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].innerText;
```